# How do I get a Fragment's variable from a class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a class whose method builds a string using the variable from a Fragment, if that Fragment is visible.

I am currently attempting to get the fragment this way, but findFragmentById is returning null:

```
val fragment = (mContext as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_holder) as PaymentFragment


val value = fragment.value
```

Here is the Fragment:

```
class PaymentFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var value: Int

}
```

What is the best way to get that fragment's value from the class?

Comment: fragments are typically quite independent, reusable components, having a fragment _returning_ something to an activity isn't really seen too much anymore, but you could make a shared viewmodel.

Comment: otherwise, make the variable static. for kotlin, you'd use a companion object to achieve this. but it all feels very hacky.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I will probably use viewmodels in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
val fragment=  PaymentFragment()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment).commit()
```

then you can use value with this:

```
val value = fragment.value
```

and you Fragment need delete "private" like this:

```
var value: Int = 0
```